# Problem in downloading a release artifact from a private github repo with golang

Tags: go

To download an specific file from a release in a private github repo, when I am executing

```
  curl -H 'Authorization: token my_github_token' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
  -O \
  -L https://github.com/privateorg/privaterepo/releases/download/v.0.10/product-v.0.10-darwin-amd64.tar.gz
```

it correctly downloads the file, but when I am trying to do so in Golang via my function as:

```
func dl(address, fileName string, headers map[string]string) error {

client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", address, nil)
for k, v := range headers {
    req.Header.Set(k, v)
}

response, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer func() {
    _ = response.Body.Close()
}()
..... rest of the function
```

and then call it via

```
url := "https://github.com/privateorg/privaterepo/releases/download/v.0.10/product-v.0.10-darwin-amd64.tar.gz"
err := Download(url, zipTarget, map[string]string{
        "Authorization": "token my_github_token",
        "Accept":        "application/vnd.github.v3.raw",
    });
```

My `client.Do(req)` call receives 404 error. Can you please guiding me what I am missing?

Comment: your code actually seems fine. best guesses would be to check the error value for `NewRequest` and verify the address your `dl` func receives.

Comment: DO NOT OMIT ANY ERROR in GO.